# Pandas apply on index of dataframe with a mult-iindex

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with an index like

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], [0, 1]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
       names=['I1', 'I2'])
```

Now I would like to apply a function to index I1.
If it were a simple column I would do something like

```
df['I1'] = df['I1'].apply(lamdba x :...)
```

How can I apply this to an Index in a df with a multi-index?

Comment: Can you explain more? What kind of function?

Comment: With `MultiIndex`, use `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need `rename`:

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: 'a' + x, level=0)
```

Or [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for select level of `MultiIndex`, `map` and then create [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
idx = df.index.get_level_values('I1').map(lambda x: 'a' + x)

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx, df.index.get_level_values('I2')])
```

because I get :

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(idx, level='I1')
```

> ValueError: Level values must be unique: ['aA', 'aA', 'aB', 'aB', 'aC', 'aD', 'aD', 'aE', 'aE', 'aF', 'aF', 'aG', 'aG'] on level 0

**Sample**:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], [0, 1]],
       labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
       names=['I1', 'I2'])

df = pd.DataFrame([0] * 13, index=mux, columns=['a'])
```

---

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: 'a' + x, level=0)
print(df)
       a
I1 I2   
aA 0   0
   1   0
aB 0   0
   1   0
aC 1   0
aD 0   0
   1   0
aE 0   0
   1   0
aF 0   0
   1   0
aG 0   0
   1   0
```